# ASP.NET Resource File, Resource Manager for Language Translation

Tags: c#, asp.net, resourcemanager

Spending hours on this.  Thinking my thought process might be off..

I wanted to create one point of entry for language translation across different libraries and applications.

What I did was the following:

Created New Class Library Project called Translations
At Root Level Added New Item - MyStrings.en-US.resx file
Populated resx file
resx - Access Modifier set to Public

At Root Level of Translations Project Added New Item Class - Translator
Added Property

```
public class Translator
    {
        private ResourceManager _translationManager;
        public ResourceManager TranslationManager
        {
            get
            {
                if (_translationManager == null)
                {
                    _translationManager = new ResourceManager("MyStrings", this.GetType().Assembly);
                }
                return _translationManager;
            }
        }

    }
```

In WebSite (not web project but website) Added Reference to Translations Project
In the code behind declared

```
        private Translator _translate;
        public Translator Translate
        {
            get
            {
                if (_translate == null)
                {
                    _translate = new Translator();
                }
                return _translate;
            }
        }
```

then in a LINQ statement

```
Title = TranslationManager.GetString(appsAvailable.Value.ResourceKey, CurrentCulture)

ResourceKey does have a value
CurrentCulture = en-US
```

And I am getting this error

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or
>   the neutral culture.  Make sure "MyStrings.resources" was correctly
>   embedded or linked into assembly "Translations" at compile time, or
>   that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully
>   signed.

When I look at my bin/obj/debug folder I am seeing this Translations.MyStrings.en-US.resources

which is not the name it is looking for.  I have tried to modify the "basename" for the manager from "MyStrings" to 'Translations.MyStrings"  but I get a similar error stating "Translations.MyStrings.resources" can't be found.  I have also tried just saying okay forget the culture right now let's access it "Translations.MyStrings.en-US" as the base name.  and it says it still can not find it.

Any ideas of where I am going wrong? I am thinking it needs to be copied somewhere so the software finds it but don't know where it goes?  Or am I trying to do something that it is not meant to do?

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just download MAT (Multilingual App Toolkit) for Visual Studio. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MultilingualAppToolkit.MultilingualAppToolkit-18308

This is the way to go to translate and maintain your projects in Visual Studio ;-)
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/matdev/